# Models v Records - confused

Tags: plugin-development, database, models, records

If a Model can be used to save entries, what is a Record for? Is it literally just to define the schema? I've seen a few examples where the defineAttributes methods have duplication of code too, so I'm a little confused...

Comment: There is a good explanation of models vs. records in Craft here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2973/57

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I'd like to echo one of the comments on that article in that it would be great if this detail was in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but I don't think a model can be used to save entries. You populate a model, then populate a record with that model and save it. Once saved, you get data from the db as a record, then populate a model with it to pass that to a view, for instance.

If everything works as it should, a record is never used outside the service.

Comment: Nailed it. In rare instances, you might modify a record's properties just before saving (or just after retrieving). But if that data ever leaves your service layer, it should do so as a model.

Comment: How does this work when updating an existing record? https://gist.github.com/russback/f6d96809a459e3872363 shows how I'm currently doing it but it feels a little odd to have to declare a model just to access the allErrors property (it doesn't exist on the BaseRecord class.

Comment: The underlying CActiveRecord class contains hasErrors and getErrors methods.